# Android WebView does not scroll into Viewport on form input

Tags: android, webview

We having a mobile website with some input forms. When I test it with the default mobile browser on an Samsung Galaxy S II everything works fine.

We have build an "app" with just a `WebView` calling this page. So the behaviour should be the same.

But when I use the app and i enter some form input and hit "Next", the webview does not scroll automatically into the viewport, so I have to guess which input form is focused. I just can't see the "next" input form.

So with the default browser, the input form scrolls into viewport automatically. When using the app it doesn't. Does anybody know why? Is this a bug in WebView?

Comment: It's been about 3 years and I am facing this issue. Did you perhaps come across a solution for this?

Comment: so sad to see your comments while searching for solutions